# How to change attributed stringkey foreground color in button A from button B?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have button A with customized attributed text. Is there a way that I can change it foreground color with button B?

This is button A:

```
    let buttonA: UIButton = {
    let bt = UIButton(type: .system)
    bt.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "127", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black])
    bt.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)
    return bt
}()
```

I would like to change only color and keep in mind string in NSMutableAttributedString is dynamic so I don't have the exact string to use to create another attributedText and do this from button B.

```
let attributedTextFromButtonB = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "127", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
bt.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)  
buttonA.setAttributedTitle(attributedTextFromButtonB, for: .normal)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this,

```
if let btnBTitle = buttonB.title(for: .normal) {
     let attributedTextFromButtonB = NSMutableAttributedString(string: btnBTitle, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])  
     buttonA.setAttributedTitle(attributedTextFromButtonB, for: .normal)
}
```